# Python == operator issue

Tags: python, operators

I'm a beginner with python and I am trying to create an if statement to check if three variable may contain certain numbers.
So for example I want to check if var1 or var2 or var3 contain two numbers.

```
if ((var1 or var2 or var3) == (23 and 25)):
```

So basically I want to check if 23 and 25 are in var1,var2 or var3 and only pass the condition if they are. So to be clear 23 could be in var1, var2 or var3 and 25 could also be in any of them.

Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: *"Am I doing this correctly?"* - why don't you **test it and find out?** (Spoiler alert: no.)

Comment: `or` and `and` don't work the same way in Python as they do in English. Study up on those and look for examples.

Comment: I think you want `if all(x in (v1,  v2,  v3) for x in (23, 25))`, or use a set `{23,25}.issubset([v1,v2,v3])`

Comment: I just woke up to the application: *var* is variable, not *variant list*.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
if 23 in (var1, var2, var3) or 25 in (var1, var2, var3)
```

There are more sophisticated ways to do this, but it would be good for you to start with understanding this one.

Python is fairly close to English, but still not quite the same. Make sure to look at the syntax!

Comment: Doesn't the OP want both conditions to be true?

Comment: I am not entirely sure from his comment or code. @OP, if you want both to be true, just replace 'or' by 'and'.